# What is best practice for timezone handling in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timezone

This has been asked before but not the answer I am looking for. I am storing all my dates in MYSQL in UTC/GMT. When I extract data fora user that references time is it better to use the CONVERT_TZ construct...

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(mytime,'UTC',usertimezone) as mytime FROM table
```

or is it better to temporarily set the session zone in Mysql and then do normal queries?

```
SET time_zone = usertimezone;
```

And if I use the second, do I just do that once for each user session or if I am not using a persistent open, do I need to set it before each query?

Comment: Any reason not to let this be done in the client instead?

Comment: It is a lot of work to process every time value before display. Trying to do a minimum of coding. :)

Comment: You store the user's timezone and then use that in converting UTC to their timezone.

Comment: @DougWolfgram: Well you're only moving the work to the database, for no particularly obvious reason. The work still needs to be done, and it shouldn't be significantly more code to do this at the client side...

Comment: Does this help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices ?

Comment: I think I want to always store in UTC, but when I am using date math for a user (give me the last 30 days worth of data) I should used the CONVERT_TZ so I get HIS last 30 days. Otherwise, if I am just formatting it for display, do the conversion at the display end. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored in `TIMESTAMP` type columns, then you should `SET time_zone` and MySQL will automatically convert to/from UTC on retrieval/insertion—you don't need to do anything more.  This is the recommended approach.

Comment: I rarely use Timestamp, but rather, datetime. This application is high volume data collection and I want to write several records with the exact same timestamp.

Comment: @DougWolfgram: You can still provide a given value to a `TIMESTAMP` field ([automatic initialisation and updating](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) are *optional*, albeit active by default).  `DATETIME` is a different beast altogether and does not store any notion of timezone (so MySQL *cannot* perform any implicit conversion to the session `time_zone`).

Comment: I dunno. When I use set_timezone to set my session to UTC it appears to force datetime inserts to convert.

Comment: it’s a signed 32 bit number, the minimum date is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and the maximum is 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC (that’s 2^31-1), so i don't think this gonna help you a lot

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore: what on Earth does that have to do with this question, or my answer?

Comment: @eggyal I was  referring TIMESTAMP limitation for storing dates.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore: I know what you were referring to, but what bearing does it have on this question/answer?

Comment: Calm down I did not find storing dates as timestamp is a best practice  to handle timezone. I agree your solutions is right if we store date as timestamp.

Answer (score 11):

- Use `TIMESTAMP` if you want MySQL to do the conversion based on the `time_zone` setting of the current session.
- Use `DATETIME` if you are returning UTC to your application for it to handle the conversion there.  (This would be my preference.)
- Don't try to mix these up.  `DATETIME` will not do anything with the `time_zone` setting, and `TIMESTAMP` cannot be assumed to be UTC when it is returned to your application unless you are absolutely sure that `time_zone` is set to UTC.

Comment: It's worth noting that `TIMESTAMP` is limited in range from the years 1970 to 2038, which might factor into the decision.