# Convert server date timestamp stored in central time based on user timezone

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, plsql, java-8

The dates with timestamps are inserted/saved into the database with datatype datetime in Central Time (CT) regardless of the timezone. When I access the application in eastern timezone and retrieve those dates from my time zone, which is Eastern Time (ET), I would like the dates to render in my Eastern Time zone and not central time. For example, if the stored date is 2018-11-19 13:08:44 in the database in Central Time, I need to get it back as 2018-11-19 14:08:44 if I connect from Eastern or 2018-11-19 12:08:44 if I connect from Mountain Time Zone. I have a Java bean and I need to set the retrieved date converted to my timezone and display the date in a csv file. How do I accomplish this? Java is the server side language. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is best practice for timezone handling in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254825/what-is-best-practice-for-timezone-handling-in-mysql)

Comment: You will need to provide technical detail as to the exact data types of your database columns and your Java objects. Explain how you move the date-time values via Java. Also, you should search before posting. Your issues have most likely been addressed already. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough detail to give you precise help. But here are some general guidelines.

## Data type of column

To record moments, your database table column must be defined with a type akin to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. The equivalent in MySQL seems to be [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Beware of tools with an anti-feature of dynamically applying a default time zone to the value extracted from the database. This creates the illusion of the stored value having that particular time zone. This is certainly not the case in MySQL 8 where `TIMESTAMP` is documented as always being stored in UTC.

Do *not* use the type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` as that records only the date and time-of-day but no context of time zone or offset-from-UTC. The equivalent in MySQL seems to be [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

## UTC is your friend

Generally best to track moments as seen through UTC, that is, with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. You should learn to think of UTC as the One True Time, all other zones and offsets are but mere variations. All programmers and sysadmins should be working in UTC for their logging, debugging, data storage, and data exchange. Apply a time zone only as required by business logic or for presentation to the user.

> inserted/saved into the database with datatype datetime in Central Time (CT) regardless of the timezone

I have no idea what that means.

If you want to track moments, specific points on the timeline, you must have a time zone or offset-from-UTC. As I suggested, using UTC itself is strongly recommended.

In *java.time*, the `Instant` class represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Oddly, the JDBC 4.2 standard does not require support for the two most commonly used *java.time* classes: `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. The third class for moments, `OffsetDateTime`, is required. No matter, we can easily convert. Specify an offset of zero using the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.toOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or skip the `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Send to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Notice that all this code is working in UTC exclusively. No time zones involved, just an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

## Time zones

> Central Time (CT) …Eastern Time (ET) …

These are not time zones. These are pseudo-zones, commonly used in the media, but never to be used in your programming.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

### `ZoneId`

While `ZoneOffset` is for mere offsets (a number of hours-minutes-seconds), the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class is for time zones (a history of past, present, and  future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

We can apply a `ZoneId` to an `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` to view that moment through the wall-clock time (offset) used by the people of that region.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Text

To create strings in standard ISO 8601 format representing the value of our *java.time* objects, simply call `toString`.

To generate text in other custom formats, or even to automatically localize, see the `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` classes. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many many times already.

## Refactoring

You mentioned "datetime" in your Question. If you meant that your column is literally of type `DATETIME`, you have a mess on your hands. You should refactor your database to use proper types.

For that refactoring, extract the values from that column, retrieving as the Java type [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). This class is for a date and time-of-day but lacking the context of a zone or offset. As such, this value is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;  // Retrieving value from a MySQL 8 column of type `DATETIME`.
```

You claim to know the time zone intended, but not recorded, for those values. Keep in mind that you are only guessing. You do not really know for sure what the original zone/offset was, as that value was discarded.

But if you are certain of the intended zone, specify as a `ZoneId`. By "Central Time (CT)" I will assume you meant a time zone such as `America/Chicago`.

```
ZoneId zChicago = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
```

Apply this `ZoneId` object to each retrieved `LocalDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zChicago ) ;
```

Convert our `ZonedDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime` given the support required by the JDBC 4.2 spec. (Your JDBC driver may optionally support `ZonedDateTime`, so you could try that if you like.)

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;  // Stripping away the rich time zone information, trading it for simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC.
```

Send to the database in a *new* column of type `TIMESTAMP`, as should have originally been done when the database was designed.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Notice that the `OffsetDateTime` object we are sending is not in UTC. That object will carry the offset used by the Chicago-region at that time-of-day on that date (several hours behind UTC). Of course that offset varies because of politician-imposed anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

But you should not have to worry about the offset in the `OffsetDateTime`. Your MySQL-specific JDBC driver should take care of converting to UTC per the requirements of that type as defined in MySQL. You should do a bit of testing to be sure this is working properly, and according to your understanding. If while debugging you want to see the moment of this `OffsetDateTime` in UTC, convert to an `Instant`: `odt.toInstant().toString()`.

When you have finished populating the new column of type `TIMESTAMP`, drop the old column of type `DATETIME`.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL.]